# log4j formatted printing in java

Tags: java, log4j

This is my first java program in 10 years. I am trying to do formatted printing while logging errors with log4j 2.

My code is

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class Feeder {

    private  static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Feeder.class);

    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {

        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                logger.info("Hello World " + i);
                Thread.sleep(4000);
                int x = 100 / 0;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            StackTraceElement var[] = ex.getStackTrace();
            for(StackTraceElement s: var){
                logger.error("Error in Filename = %s", s.getFileName());
                logger.error("Error in Class = " + s.getClassName());
                logger.error("Error in line number " + s.getLineNumber());
                logger.error("Error in method " + s.getMethodName());
            }

            //logger.error(ex.);
            logger.error(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

The log spits the following

```
03 Oct 2014 12:12:46,302 INFO  com.bluepoint.Feeder - Hello World 0
03 Oct 2014 12:12:50,304 ERROR com.bluepoint.Feeder - Error in Filename = %s
```

How do I get the file name instead of

> %s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use method from String.

```
System.out.println(String.format("This is [%s] test", name));
```

in your case, it would be:

```
logger.error(String.format("Error in Filename = %s", s.getFileName()));
```

For more formatting options: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html

Answer (score 4):

Logger uses {} as its placeholder, not %s. Just swap that out.